# getting error with phpunit feature test in laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm using phpunit to test my laravel application. Storing and retrieving works but the delete test throws an error `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\Borrower] 1`

Here's my test created for the delete functionality.

```
public function test_delete_borrower()
{
    $user = User::factory()
        ->has(LoanRequest::factory()->count(5))
        ->create();


    $response = $this->delete('borrower/'. $user->id );

    $data = $response->getOriginalContent()['message'];

    dd($data);
}
```

And in `web.php`

```
Route::resource('borrower', 'App\Http\Controllers\BorrowerController');
```

Here's a screenshot from `php artisan r:l`
[screenshot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eTKM.png)

What would be the culprit of this?

Comment: You will have to share your controller as this test has nothing wrong with it.

Comment: As mentioned please show your controller, as you are using a resource route which is using Implicit Route Model Binding, it expects the naming convention to follow.